# pretty printer help: object has no attribute

Tags: gdb

I am writing my first pretty printer, have some trouble. My gdb is 7.7.

Here is the C++ code I like to debug:

```
enum Country
{
    CHINA,
    USA
};

class Foo
{
   public:
       Foo(int _v, enum Country c) {v = _v; m_country = c;}
       ~Foo() { v = -1; }

       int v;
       enum Country m_country;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f(10, CHINA);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my printer:

```
import gdb 

class FooPrinter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.v = val

    def to_string(self):
        # because v is integer, a simpler way is:
        # return self.v['v']
        v = "v=" + str(self.v['v'])

        f = self.m_country['m_country']
        if (f == 0):
            c = "CHINA"
        elif (f == 1):                                                                                                                                                                       
            c = "USA"                                                                                                                                                                        
        else:                                                                                                                                                                                
            c = "unknown"

        c = "c=" + c

        ret = v + '\n' + c

        return ret


def lookup_type (val):
    if str(val.type) == 'Foo':
        return FooPrinter(val)
    return None

gdb.pretty_printers.append (lookup_type)
```

When I run the printer in gdb, I get this error:

```
(gdb) source printer.py 
(gdb) p f
Python Exception <class 'AttributeError'> 'FooPrinter' object has no attribute 'm_country':
```

I guess I need to somehow modify `__init__` to take an extra country argument, but if so, how should I update the rest of code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
    f = self.m_country['m_country']
```

Here I think you want to examine `self.v` instead:

```
    f = self.v['m_country']
```

Note that you can also get all the enumeration constant names from the enum type.  So, you can replace the chained `if` with a simpler lookup.  This is nice if the enum is larger than a couple of constants.